# regarding the image tag of html how to give source path of image

Tags: html, image, path

How can I add an image from my C or D drive directly into an HTML file without bringing it to the folder that has the HTML file?

For example, if I have a file with which its path is:

```
C:\Users\OMKAR\OneDrive\Desktop\memories\IMG20221004055341.jpg
```

can I include it in my HTML file without bringing it to the folder where the HTML file is?

Comment: Are you developing off your harddrive and not running a server?

Comment: Many will probably tell you that's a bad idea. The site will get broken if the images are ever moved. Most sites use an images folder just one level away from the HTML files so the pages can use relative links that will work no matter where the folders get moved.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply do it like this:

```html
<img src="C:\Users\OMKAR\OneDrive\Desktop\memories\IMG20221004055341.jpg"/>
```

Since the file isn't in the same folder, you just have to use the absolute path of the file!

Answer (score 0):

This will only be possible if this image is only loaded locally on your machine via the absolute path as in the example below

```
<img src="C:\Users\OMKAR\OneDrive\Desktop\memories\IMG20221004055341.jpg"/>
```

If not, you'll need to copy it to the server where the HTML file is hosted and include the folder path as usual.